# How to extract rows in Excel with a given name by function 'xlsread' in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, data-import

I have 100 Excel sheets of financial statement to extract selected data. For instance, the first sheet is from company A, its 'Total assets' item is in A10, but in the second sheet the 'Total assets' is in A17, the third in A12....

So every financial statement's items have different positions in their Excel sheet. Is there any way I can extract them by specify their name, such as 'Total assets', 'Other earning assets' etc, then I don't need to read their location one by one.

Comment: Do you know how to get a matrix of data for each sheet? If so, and if the 'Total assets' item is always in the first column, you can have a while loop that looks for that string.

Comment: @Squazic, would you please give me an example how to use while loop to search string? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a few example rows of what the data you get from `xlsread` looks like?

Comment: @Squazic, would you please leave an email address, I can send you a sample of a financial statement sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry about the delay. You'll want to import the data using

```
[num,txt] = xlsread('EXCELFILEHERE');
```

`num` will be a matrix of the numerical values while `txt` is a cell array of all the text values. Next you'll need to search `txt` for your desired phrase using something like

```
[row,col] = find(ismember(txt,'Total Assets')==1)
```

This will give you a list of columns and the corresponding rows where you'll find that phrase in `txt`. Then it's just a matter of plugging that row back into `num` to get the data you need. Keep in mind that the sizes of `num` and `txt` might be a bit off depending on how your data is formatted. I suggest `.xls` files if you can.

Comment: You can also use `[num,txt,raw]` and search the `raw` data. That way, there won't be any offset that can throw you off when switching between the `num` and `txt` variables.